# can not mapping entity when using AWS DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, mapping, entity

I am begin with dynamoDB. I using annotion mapping enity follow :

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "ProductCatalogz")
public static class Book {
    private int id;+
    private String title;+
    private String ISBN;+
    private Set<String> bookAuthors;+

    // private DimensionType dimensionType;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "Id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Title")
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "ISBN")
    public String getISBN() {
        return ISBN;
    }

    public void setISBN(String ISBN) {
        this.ISBN = ISBN;
    }
}
```

and

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    AWSCredentials credentials = new PropertiesCredentials(
     Tester2.class.getResourceAsStream("/AwsCredentials.properties"));

     client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials);
     Region usWest2 = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1);
     client.setRegion(usWest2);

     Book book = new Book();
     book.setId(1);
     book.setTitle("Book 502");
     book.setISBN("5555555555555");
     book.setBookAuthors(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("Author1",
         "Author2")));
     // book.setDimensions(dimType);

     DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);
     mapper.save(book);
}
```

But when I run this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" ResourceNotFoundException: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2, AWS Request ID: NSG3K0BQOBCPNQONE8, AWS Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException, AWS Error Message: Requested resource not found
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:644)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:338)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:190)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1245)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.updateItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1026)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:636)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:483)
at test.Tester2.main(Tester2.java:47)
```

please help me

Answer (score 9):

The message `Requested resource not found` means that Dynamo DB table is not found. You should create it first through AWS console, API, or CLI.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that you have set the endpoint on the client

```
BasicAWSCredentials b = new BasicAWSCredentials("Access Key ID","Secret Access Key");           
AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(b);
client.setEndpoint("dynamodb.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com");
```

Refer http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ddb_region for the complete list of End Points for DynamoDB